# Numbered list of items in a for loop

Tags: python

My python skills are rusty on this one.

I have a list of items.  I want to create an id for them and build a dictionary.

example:

```
users = ["John","Peter","Alice"]
```

I want to create an outcome like

```
users_dict = {"u1":"John","u2":"Peter","u3":"Alice"}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a for loop that will dynamically create u + integer.  I may be dealing with a large qty of items in the list.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You are probably looking for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 11):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with a formatted string as the keys:

```
>>> {f"u{i}": user for i, user in enumerate(users, start=1)}

{'u1': 'John', 'u2': 'Peter', 'u3': 'Alice'}
```

This goes through your users, creates the key `u*` for each user where `*` is the position in the original list (starting from 1 as per your desired output), and assigns it the user name

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
users = ["John","Peter","Alice"]

newusers = {}
for x in range(len(users)):
   newusers['u' + str(x+1)] = users[x]

newusers                                                                                                                                                                                          
# {'u1': 'John', 'u2': 'Peter', 'u3': 'Alice'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open Jupyter notebook and play (minimal attention to documentation required).

You start with your list

```
users = ["John","Peter","Alice"]
```

Then you need size of the list

```
len(users)
```

Now, you need list of all integers from 1 to the size. You can get it with range:

```
range(len(users))
```

So to get a list of all integers starting 1, you do:

```
list(range(1, len(users) + 1))
```

But for the future processing, you may prefer this form:

```
[i + 1 for i in range(len(users))]
```

because you can easily add prefix:

```
['u'+str(i + 1) for i in range(len(users))]
```

Now you combine two lists:

```
zip(['u'+str(i + 1) for i in range(len(users))], users)
```

and enjoy your dictionary:

```
dict(zip(['u'+str(i + 1) for i in range(len(users))], users))
```

Answer (score -1):

> It is pretty simple

```
# initializing lists 
test_values = ["John","Peter","Alice"] 
hint = "u"
```

**using naive method 
to convert lists to dictionary**

```
res = {} 
for index, value in enumerate(test_values):
    res[hint+str(index+1)] = value 
del test_values # memory efficient
```

**Printing resultant dictionary**

`print ("Resultant dictionary is : " +  str(res))`

*Then answer is like*

> {"u1":"John","u2":Peter","u3":"Alice"}

Comment: @user1496433 specifically asks how to "dynamically create u + integer", which your answer does not provide. Actually I'm not quite sure what it _does_ provide.